# How can I Hide XML Fields And Reuse that file for Another Activity?

Tags: android, xml, reusability

I want hide some fields in existed XML and use that XML as Input for Another Activity

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Can you share your code, Then i will tell how to do this .

Comment: please provide some more details..

Comment: In My XML i have 20 edit Texts but i want show 8 for each type .in my case i want reuse the one screen having all 20 fields with hiding the some fields based on type

Comment: i need to reuse that xml file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define all fields that are actually in your xml. When you want to hide one (such as a textview) do this:

```
textview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to bring something back use:

```
textview1.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

Comment: when i am doing like this the padding is problem for me suppose one field gone in that place gap is shown?

Comment: Not if you you use gone, but there will be a gap if you use View.Invisible, I must go to work, will check in later

Comment: i use same xml name for alla activities ?